# How to resolve remote application null object reference, when you cannot reproduce?

Tags: c#, debugging

So I am receiving null reference error (getting it via Log4Net in my email).
Standard.

Analysis:
- Cannot reproduce on localhost
- Cannot reproduce on remote
- Customers from Australia are getting errors (some yes, some no)

What can I do to somehow get a clue what is going on?
I know which method is throwing an error, and now I tried to put old school try catch and emailing me the values of objects when catch happens.

Anything else to deal with this annoying things?

Comment: You need to show some code of the method which shows the error.

Comment: you should raise the log-level of Log4Net and dump the stack trace to the log. Deploy Debug builds. This should give you the line number, where the null ref occurs.

Answer (score -1):

I think that one thing coming from SOLID principles is especially helpful in such a case - **Single Responsibility Principle**.

As long as you avoid two hundred lines methods, divide you code into small, atomic, testable units it is easy to determine which part of code throws an exception, even without detailed log.

I think that suggestions as "deploying debug builds", "raising log-level" are not always possible cause often software deployment is so complicated(and raising logging level can cause some funny effects like getting you log file to 10GB size in a minute when application is live) that is almost impossible to get done.

Using Resharper is another possibility to track possible null reference exceptions cause it suggests and underlines all lines when such a exception is possible.

You can also decorate your parameters with `[NotNull]` attribute - but this is the case when null as parameter causes exception.